# getting error for knife bootstrap on ubuntu chef node

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, root, chef

Getting knife bootstrap error on ubuntu chef node

> $ knife bootstrap  52.8.178.221 -x ubuntu -i ~/Keys/chef1.pem

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/chef’: Permission denied
52.8.178.221 bash: line 35: /etc/chef/validation.pem: No such file or directory
52.8.178.221 chmod: cannot access ‘/etc/chef/validation.pem’: No such file or directory
52.8.178.221 mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/chef’: Permission denied
52.8.178.221 bash: line 68: /etc/chef/trusted_certs/ashishk.crt: No such file or directory
52.8.178.221 bash: line 95: /etc/chef/client.rb: No such file or directory
52.8.178.221 bash: line 104: /etc/chef/first-boot.json: No such file or directory
52.8.178.221 Starting first Chef Client run...
52.8.178.221 bash: line 110: chef-client: command not found
```

user on chef-node should have sudo permissions so i added

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
ubuntu  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

still getting  error :

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/chef’: Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution "--sudo --use-sudo-password" helped doing it !

```
$knife bootstrap  52.8.178.221 -x ubuntu -i ~/Keys/chef1.pem --sudo --use-sudo-password
```